# Angular6 Post Method Wrong Output

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I am using Post Method for my Login in Angular 6, I was always getting Failed to Login when I even gave correct Login Credentials and when i debug my code i found its sending headers as null even if I included my headers.

This is my code when I debug and its showing response is not defined:

```
case 'json':default:return res$.pipe(map(function (res) { return res.body; }));
```

My Ts File

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { RequestOptions, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  baseUrl = "http://localhost:3000/api/auth";
  userToken: any;
  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
  };

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  login(loginData: any) {
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl, loginData, this.httpOptions)
    .pipe(
      map((response: Response) => {
        const user = response.json();
        if (user) {
          localStorage.setItem('token', user.token);
          this.userToken = user.token;
        }
      })
    )
  }

}
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

HttpClient does `response.json()` for you, so it only returns the body of the response. Also you probably do not need to set any header options, it should be *application/json* by default.

```
login(loginData: any) {
  return this.http.post(this.baseUrl, loginData);

}
```

Should be enough. This will return an observable you can subscribe to.

So in your component you can do:

```
this.authService.login(data).subscribe((user) => {
if (user) {
 localStorage.setItem('token', user.token);
}
else {
// What to do when there is no token
// Ideally you would want to throw an error on the server along the     
// lines of code 403. 
} 
});
```

If you do return a status code like 403 you need to catch the error though, like this: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/catch.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer... But I can't understand as I am new to Angular, so can u explain in detail...If possible with some answer

Comment: Ya I am now getting LoggedIn in my console but how to assign that token value to my localStorage bcs its giving cant assign object value to string....

Comment: What is the type of user.token? If it is an object you would have to do something like JSON.stringify(user.token) before.

Comment: No I have commented wrong.... Now this is my code this.authservice.login(this.loginData).subscribe((user) => {
      if(user)
        localStorage.setItem('token', user.token);
        console.log("Logged In");
    }... Its giving property token doesnt exist on type object

Comment: With that code you would always console.log Logged in even if user is undefined. console.log(user) please.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean. If you subscribe((user) => {console.log(user);}); What's the result?

Comment: Ya I am getting token in the console

Comment: Then you have no user object with a property token, but your server returns the token directly. I updated the code to reflect this.

Comment: I am getting this as my output {token: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJsb2dpbiI6I…zM2fQ.ekTr_2VSq8sbfxKBeViJcqHXoqZwOlQ-uXbVc63p9DY"}.... I think thats an object with token as my key... Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Getting this error if I added the code u edited...Argument of type 'Object' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

Comment: You're right, misunderstood your last comment then. user.token is defined in that case.

Comment: Ya no problem but if I use user.token its giving error, property token doesn't exist on type object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179207/discussion-between-christian-s-and-gvs-akhil).